# OAuth, Twitter and Indentity - who am I?

Tags: oauth, twitter, identity, twitter-oauth

Once authenticated to Twitter via OAuth I did not see a good call to get your username.
How is this supposed to work? I'd like to pull back things like Twitter username, firstname, lastname, etc... basic profile stuff. Should the OAuth handshake give me my username?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/account/verify_credentials
```

It'll show you all information (you'ld normally get of any other user) of the OAuth-authenticated-account =)!

Comment: awesome! exactly the type of thing I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 3):

First, Twitter includes the screen_name parameter in the access token response. Second, you can call http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json to get the full profile which will also include the name (JSON key 'name'). Twitter does not provide email addresses.

Comment: Not sure how to get at the response using that Groovy/Grails plugin so the verify_credentials was the path I went down.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried any of these [libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries)? I've tried just about all of the php ones and all that I tried had examples on how to get the user data.

Comment: I'm using the Grails OAuth plugin which is a little light in the documentation dept. Wonder if there is a call back over to twitter I can make that would reveal the username. Then I would just store it in the session.